# Prism Unity - WPF Bind subclass in ViewModel

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, prism

i have a prism unity application, how can i get a subclass inside viewmodel property changed?

How can i implement the CanExecute with complex object in my viewmodel?

MODEL

```
public class WardModel : BindableBase
{
    private string _Id;

    public string Id
    {
        get { return _Id; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _Id, value); }
    }
}
```

VIEWMODEL

```
public class ucAddViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private readonly IUnityContainer _unityContainer;
    private readonly IRegionManager _regionManager;

    private WardModel _Ward;

    public WardModel Ward
    {
        get
        {
            return _Ward;
        }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _Ward, value);

            CanSaveExecute = Ward.Id != null && Ward.Id != string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

XAML

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Ward.Id, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,0,0,10"></TextBox>
```

Comment: What is the problem/exception you're facing? What is `CanExecute` and `CanSaveExecute`?

Answer (score 0):

Execute and CanExecute methods are used with Commands, you cannot use them in accessors.
If you want to make sure your Id doesn't take wrong value, just put your validation rules into Model class.

```
 public class WardModel : BindableBase
    {
        private string _Id;
        public string Id
        {
            get { return _Id; }
            set
            {
                if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value)) SetProperty(ref _Id, value);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to refresh your command after a property of your viewModel changed.

Model:

```
public class MyModel : BindableBase
{
   private string Name _name;
   public Name 
   {
     get { return _name; }
     set { SetProperty(ref _name, value); }
   }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class MyViewModel : BindableBase
{
   private DelegateCommand _myCommand;
   public DelegateCommand MyCommand => _myCommand ?? (_myCommand = new DelegateCommand(Execute, CanExecute));

   //your method that will be executed
   private void Execute()
   {
       //Do sth.
   }

   //will be triggered through MyCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
   private bool CanExecute()
   {
       //you validating logic, e.g.
       return MyComplexObject != null;
   }

   private MyModel _myComplexObject;
   public MyModel MyComplexObject
   {
      get { return _myComplexObject; }
      set 
      {
          SetProperty(ref _myComplexObject, value);
          //Trigger the CanExecuteChanged Event
          MyCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
      }
   }
}
```